# Count specific value within one row

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, array-formulas, counting, countif

I search for a formula which counts a specific value (for example the letter "Y") within one (1) row witch have five columns (the letter "Y" can be in multiple columns of the row). And put this counting number in a cell (B2). I want to get a number of the duplicates.

I only can find countif solutions witch gives me the duplicates for specific values in just a column like `=COUNTIF(A1:A8;"Y")`. But this is not a solution for my case.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C&D2:D); 
 COUNTIFS(IF(A2:D="Y"; ROW(A2:A)); ROW(A2:A)); ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you, but I have more than 600 rows and I need a formula which can handle that automatically. You know? Also I want to get the result in another Table B.

I tested your formula for one row with my table structure but this doesnt work for me:
`=ARRAYFORMULA(WENN(LÄNGE('sc-hreflang-import'!A8:A); 
 ZÄHLENWENNS(WENN('sc-hreflang-import'!A8:X="*"&'hreflang-deklaration'!$C$8&"*"; ZEILE('sc-hreflang-import'!A8:A)); ZEILE('sc-hreflang-import'!A8:A)); ))`

Comment: this formula works even for 2000 rows... can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Ok it works now except the wildcard I used. Is there no opportunity tu use a wildcard? --> for example `"*Y*"` ? If I use this wildcard I get only "0".

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A&B2:B&C2:C&D2:D), 
 COUNTIFS(IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:D, "Y|y"), ROW(A2:A)), ROW(A2:A)), ))`

Comment: What does the `LEN(xxxx)`? If I delete everything except `A2:A` in this brackets it still works. Do I need this really?

Comment: LEN checks for the length of characters. in this particular combination, logic is: IF LEN of A2 is something/anything/more than 0 - do TRUE otherwise do FALSE of IF